# Perl ole selection property iterating

Tags: perl, ms-word, selection, ole

I searched answer but did not find answer, so it brings me to register at stackowerflow. I am trying to write simple perl script using win32 ole which will iterate over all M$ word paragraphs (any text that ends with a hard return) and print only those paragraphs that matches the specified condition. The problem is that I need to access font size property. It seems to me that this property is set only once in first paragraph and later is not updated. Please see following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
#$Win32::OLE::CP = CP_UTF8;
binmode STDOUT, 'encoding(utf8)';

# OPEN FILE SPECIFIED AS FIRST ARGUMENT
my $fname=$ARGV[0];
my $fnameFullPath = `cygpath.exe -wa $fname`;
$fnameFullPath =~ s/\\/\\\\/g;
$fnameFullPath =~ s/\s*$//;
unless (-e $fnameFullPath) { print "Error: File did not exists\n"; exit 1;}

# STARTING OLE
my $Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
    || Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application','Quit')
    or die Win32::OLE->LastError();

$Word->{'Visible'} = 0;
my $doc = $Word->Documents->Open($fnameFullPath);
my $paragraphs = $doc->Paragraphs() ;
my $enumerate = new Win32::OLE::Enum($paragraphs);

# PROCESSING PARAGRAPHS
while(defined(my $paragraph = $enumerate->Next())) {

    my $text = $paragraph->{Range}->{Text};
    my $sel = $Word->Selection;
    my $font = $sel->Font;

    if ($font->{Size} == 18){
        print "Text: ", $text, "\n";
        print "Font Bold: ", $font->{Bold}, "\n";
        print "Font Italic: ", $font->{Italic}, "\n";
        print "Font Name: ", $font->{Name}, "\n";
        print "Font Size: ", $font->{Size}, "\n";
        print "=========\n";
    }
}

# CLOSING OLE
$Word->ActiveDocument->Close ;
$Word->Quit;
```

Here is output what I obtained:

```
Text: This is a doc file containing different fonts and size, document also contain header and footer (Font: TNR, Size: 18)
Font Bold: 0
Font Italic: 0
Font Name: Times New Roman
Font Size: 18
=========
Text: This is a Perl example (Font TNR, Size: 12)
Font Bold: 0
Font Italic: 0
Font Name: Times New Roman
Font Size: 18
=========
Text: This is a Python example(Font: Courier New, Size: 10)
Font Bold: 0
Font Italic: 0
Font Name: Times New Roman
Font Size: 18
=========
```

As you can see in output everywhere is Font Size 18 even if in original document are different sizes (Also font name is not updated). This brings me to assumption that $font is set only once in 1st paragraph which is processed. Thus the following condition

```
if ($font->{Size} == 18)
```

is only evaluated in 1st processed paragraph. This also supports fact that if I change condition to following (Match 2nd paragraph):

```
if ($font->{Size} == 12)
```

the output is nothing. Because first paragraph is 18 not 12 and thus the condition is false, $font is not updated any more so it wont never be true. What I am doing wrong ?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks to me that the default font for the paragraph style is Times Roman, size 18.

Comment: While, I confess, I'm not quite familiar with this module, I wonder what `$Word->Selection` should do. Perhaps it collects the information from the first paragraph only?

Comment: How about using querying the `$paragraph->{Range}` instead? Like `$sel = $paragraph->Range; $text = $sel->Text; $font = $sel->Font;`?

Comment: Hello, sorry for longer reply. AFAIK $Word->Selection is acutually selected part (header, main, footer) Tried also raina77ow suggest but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `#Insert this code` in the snippet it will work fine now.

```
# PROCESSING PARAGRAPHS

while(defined(my $paragraph = $enumerate->Next())) {

    #Insert this code
    $paragraph->{Range}->Select(); 
    sleep(1);
    #-------------

    my $text = $paragraph->{Range}->{Text};    
    my $sel = $Word->Selection;
    my $font = $sel->Font;

    if ($font->{Size} == 18){
        print "Text: ", $text, "\n";
        print "Font Bold: ", $font->{Bold}, "\n";
        print "Font Italic: ", $font->{Italic}, "\n";
        print "Font Name: ", $font->{Name}, "\n";
        print "Font Size: ", $font->{Size}, "\n";
        print "=========\n";
    }
}
```